# Suppose H is a subring of R such that for every $r∈H$ we have $r^2=e$. Prove that $H$ is commutative.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

So I know that since H is a subring of $\mathbb{R}$ that H is then by definition:

1) closed under addition

2) closed under multiplication

3) have the same multiplicative identity as $\mathbb{R}$

Am I missing anything? I think I need to only reference fact 2, which states that H is closed under multiplication for this proof.

I tried looking up on the internet how to show that a subring is commutative and did not find anything. Is the answer as simple as saying that since $\mathbb{R}$ is commutative then the subring H, is itself by definition commutative?

Or do I go about it by showing that lets say for example:

Let $r_1, r_2 \in H$ then $r_1 \times r_2 = e = r_1 \times r_2$ which is then commutative?

Comment: It seems that you are writing $e$ for the multiplicative identity of the ring, which is usually written $1$. Under your assumptions, $0 = 0^2 = 1$, which implies that $H$ and $R$ are both the trivial ring containing just one element. The trivial ring is commutative.

Comment: Why do you use $\mathbb{R}$ as notation for ring? Very confusing!

Comment: It is highly unlikely the problem meant to trivialize everything by asking about a subring of a commutative ring.

Comment: If every nonzero element squares to $e$, clearly every nonzero element is a unit, and the set of nonzero elements is a group. That makes it fall under a frequently asked group theory question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us assume that every $0 \ne r \in H$ satisfies $r^2 = e$, ruling out the case $e = 0^2 = 0$, which trivializes everything.  These words inspired by the comment of Rob Arthan to the question itself.

Let

$x, y \in H; \tag 0$

then

$x^2 = y^2 = e; \tag 1$

also,

$xy \in H, \tag{1.5}$

whence

$xyxy = (xy)^2 = e; \tag 2$

then

$yxy = eyxy = x^2yxy = x(xyxy) = xe = x, \tag 3$

and

$yx = yxe = yxy^2 = (yxy)y = xy, \tag 4$

which shows $H$ is commutative.  $OE\Delta$.

Comment: So what about the fact that the conditions were supposed to be for a subring and that they cannot hold then?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft:  nor sure I under.stand your question

Comment: your logic looks perfectly fine to me. I think he thinks I left some details out in the question but I posted it exactly as is

Comment: Please stop the practice of  duplicating solutions over and over. I mean, [you have written exactly this answer before](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2439267/29335), and [also here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/663639/29335)  and [not in detail here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/737739/29335) .  I won't speculate on why you do this, but I will suggest to you (not for the first time, I believe) to prefer duplication above diluting the answer pool with yet-another copy of the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

Commutativity means that for all $r,s\in H$ we have that $r\circ s= s\circ r$ where $\circ: H\times H\to H$ denotes the multiplication of $R$ restricted to $H$.

Now to address your question: If for all $r\in H$ we have that $r\circ r=e$, then, $r=r^{-1}$ holds for all $r\in H$. Thus, given $r,s\in H$, $$r\circ s = r^{-1}\circ s^{-1}=(s\circ r)^{-1}=s\circ r,$$ where for the last equality we used that $s\circ r\in H$.

Comment: So what about the fact that the conditions were supposed to be for a subring and that they cannot hold then?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: I think the conditions can hold, but they show that $H$ and $R$ are trivial. See my comment on the question.

Comment: @Rob My guess would be that the OP forgot some part of the question. But in either case, it calls for a clarifying comment like yours, rather than an answer like this one that misses some important details.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: absolutely!

Comment: What I have in the question is directly copy and pasted from the homework

Comment: Does this not follow then?

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft I don’t understand what you want to point at. These conditions can hold and the argument is perfectly fine.

Comment: @sampleuser: what is $0^{-1}$ in an arbitrary ring?

Comment: As you pointed out already, the assumptions imply that R is the trivial ring with 0=1. thus $0^{-1}=1$.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using $e$ to denote the multiplicative identity of the ring $R$. I will follow custom and write $1$ rather than $e$. If $H$ is a subring of a ring $R$, then the additive identity $0$ is a member of $H$. As $0^2 = 0$, if $0^2 = 1$ we have $0 = 1$ which implies $x = 1x = 0x = 0$ for every $x \in R$. Thus your hypothesis implies that $R$ (and $H$) is the trivial ring with just one element $0 = 1$. The trivial ring is commutative.

Comment: Yes I am using e to identify the multiplicative identity, Okay I will add that logic to the opening. I assume my professor wants to see both cases